# Group tuple and list maintaining order python

Tags: python

I have a list and a tuple. I know tuples are not meant to be modified, but I need to join the tuple with a list keeping order between the two, for example..

```
l1 = [(166L,), (155L,)]
l2 = [0.74, 0.25]
```

I would like

```
l3 = [[166,0.74],[155,0.25]]
```

I tried sorted(l1+l2) but this did not work giving

```
[0.25, 0.7, (155L,), (166L,)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l1 = [(166L,), (155L,)]
>>> l2 = [0.74, 0.25]
>>> zip([x for x, in l1], l2)
[(166L, 0.74), (155L, 0.25)]
>>> map(list, zip([x for x, in l1], l2))
[[166L, 0.74], [155L, 0.25]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l3 = [[l1[i][0], l2[i]] for i in range(len(l1))]
```

will work, assuming that l1 is composed of 1-tuples, and l2 is composed of single elements, and l1 and l2 have the same length.